Equivalence between K-theory for C*-algebras and K-theory for rings.
My question is motivated for the Swan’s theorem that give us an isomorphism between the $K(X)$ and $K(C(X))$. When you think as $K(C(X))$ as the algebraic K theory everything works perfectly. Because we have the equivalence between finitely generated projective modules and the vector bundles.
But when we define the K-theory for $C^*$ algebras we use the monoid generated from the projections. Then I cannot see a direct relation between projections and vector bundles.
My idea is the following, for every vector bundle over X, E, can be embedded in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then we can give a projection out E, $P_E\in Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$, such that we can consider P as a function in $C(\mathbb{C}^n)$, satisfying $P^2=P$, then we can give to every vector bundle a projection in the algebra. But I don’t know how to show that $P=P^*$.
Thanks in advance.
